# Why my options don't selected in my list multple select

Tags: php, html

Before editing my data, I wish to display the data which are already selected of the database. I successfully display the selected options when I have a simple list, but **not** when I have a multiple select list.

```
<?php
echo '
<select name="nationalite[]" multiple>
        <OPTION VALUE="">Nationalité</OPTION>
        <option value="FR"';if ($nationalite == 'FR') echo "selected"; echo'>Française</option>
        <option value="ETR"';if ($nationalite == 'ETR') echo "selected"; echo'>Etrangère</option>
</select>
';
?>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You are not properly concatenate your data. Try to check the usage of [concatenate operator](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.operators.string.php) (in french) [english link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "selected" works when I select the options, the problem is in display.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not correct !

If you want to compaction two string in php you cal use dot

Ex.:

```
<?php
   $name = "sosano";
   echo "hello" . $name;
?>
```

your correcte code is :

```
<?php
echo '
<select name="nationalite[]" multiple>
        <OPTION VALUE="">Nationalité</OPTION>
        <option value="FR" '. ($nationalite == 'FR') ? "selected" :  "".'>Française</option>
        <option value="ETR" '. ($nationalite == 'ETR') ? "selected" : "".'>Etrangère</option>
</select>
';
?>
```